# Not able to access controllers and models after hosting project

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel

I have completed my CodeIgniter project and it is uploaded on Cpanel (hosting). But I am not able to access the project from hosting. It shows `404 Page Not Found`- error.

The project is saved in `/leadgen` folder and I have updated `config.php` file to

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/leadgen";
```

It works nicely on local server

[image: Error screen shot]

Comment: Maybe your server software (apache/iis) isn't configured the same?

Comment: did you try hard coding the base url instead of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

Comment: @mk1024 yes i did, it shows same error

Comment: share folder structure

Comment: Thanks, everybody for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips!

1. Always set your values in `config.php` file after uploading to the cloud hosting.
2. Change the base_url from `$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/leadgen";` to `$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/leadgen/";`
3. If, you still experiencing problem, make sure you debug your `base_url` by entering 
   `var_dump($config['base_url']); die();` at the bottom of `config.php` file.
4. By this way, you can confirm your `base_url()` value and debug your source accordingly!

Hope it helps!